# Reversing an integer's digits is multiplicative for small digits

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, recreational-mathematics, number-systems, multiplicative-function

So my 7 year old son pointed out to me something neat about the number 12: if you multiply it by itself, the result is the same as if you took 12 *backwards* multiplied by itself, then flipped the result backwards. In other words: $$12 × 12 = 144$$$$21 × 21 = 441$$

I confidently explained to him that this was merely a coincidence.

But he then casually pointed out that the same holds true for 10, 11 and 13 (as long as you use leading zeros), $$10 × 10 = 100$$$$01 × 01 = 001$$

As if this wasn't enough, he also went on to mention that the same holds true for *addition* for those same four numbers! $$12 + 12 = 24$$ $$21+21 = 42$$

So needless to say, this is hard to chalk up to mere coincidence. Is there some non-coincidental reason for these strange findings?

Comment: Just means there is no carrying.  Works for $13$ as well ($13\times 13=169, 31\times 31=961$) or for $102$, say, but not $14$. because $4\times4=16$ would need carrying.

Comment: ... although $14$ works for addition, as does any number where both digits are less than $5$,

Comment: Maybe it is required that the sum of the ciphers of the number is no bigger than 5. Maybe it works also for 20, 22, 30 and 40...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation

Comment: Also works for $12\times 14=168$ and $41\times 21=861$, or $11\times 15=165$ or $11\times 18=198, 11\times 81=891$.

Comment: Basically, any multiplication where there is no "carrying" works.

Comment: Your son has rediscovered the "skinny numbers": https://oeis.org/A061909

Comment: Upvoting for the seven year old.

Comment: I came across the same coincidence when i was 16 and trying to avoid math homework. I used to think these are the only numbers with that property, until I wrote a computer program to find more. And more it did indeed find.

Comment: All of the answers below assume that the number base is ten.  But your son's examples work with number base eleven, twelve, and up, but not in number base 9 and lower.  Suggest limiting the problem by specifying the number base.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Suppose we have a 2 digit number $x$. We can write is in terms of its digits $a$ and $b$. When we attempt to square this number, we get an interesting result.

$$x^2=(10a+b)^2=100a^2+10(2ab)+b^2$$

We can also flip the digits (I'll use $\bar x$ to indicate this) and then square.

$$\bar x^2=(10b+a)^2=100b^2+10(2ab)+a^2$$

This result isn't very useful on its own, but if $a^2$, $b^2$, and $2ab$ are all less than $10$, then the three terms above are the three digits of $x^2$ and $\bar x^2$ respectively. It is clear from that that reversing the digits of $x$ reverses the digits of $x^2$ provided it meets those requirements. (If we switch $a$ and $b$, the first and last terms switch while the middle term is unchanged.)

Note that $10$, $11$, $12$, and $13$ (as well as $20$, $21$, $22$, $30$, and $31$) all satisfy the same condition $a^2,b^2,2ab<10$ and thus have the property you describe.

The same argument can be used for addition, since, if no digit is greater than $4$, we can add the digits individually. Rearranging the digits of such a number will apply the same rearrangement to its sum with itself.

We can play the same game with three digit numbers, but the restrictions are even greater:

$$x^2=(100a+10b+c)^2=10000a^2+1000(2ab)+100(b^2+2ac)+10(2bc)+c^2$$

If each factor multiplying a power of ten is less than ten, we have the same property. This gives us a few numbers, which you can verify all have the property.

$$100,101,102,103,110,111,112,113,120,121,122,130,200,201,202,210,211,212,220,300,301,310,311$$

Note that we have not shown that these conditions give you all the numbers for which $\bar x^2=\bar{x^2}$, though I haven't been able to find a counterexample. This argument nonetheless applies to all of the numbers you provided.

Comment: Palindromic numbers own

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1633311/prove-that-the-number-14641-is-the-fourth-power-of-an-integer-in-any-base-greate

Comment: "Note that these conditions do not give you all the numbers for which $\overline{x}^2=\overline{x^2}$, but this argument applies to all the numbers you mention. Palindromic numbers are a natural choice for a counterexample." What do you mean by this?  It seems to me that palindromes usually don't work.  For example, $191^2 = 36481$, which isn't a palindrome.  (Also, did you mean to include "400" in your list?)

Comment: @A.Rex Thanks for pointing that out. I've corrected the errors. It appears there are in fact no counterexamples less than 10000.

Comment: $2a+2b$ should be $2ab$.

Comment: Note that ​ "no counterexamples less than 10000" ​ is only when we don't allow leading zeros. ​ ​ ​ (Otherwise, 1000 is a counterexample.) ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: It was my understanding from the question that leading zeros are fine, tough it is worth noting that the we need to specify how they are treated, e. g. $1=01=001$.

Comment: Oh - I now realize that you're referring to counterexamples to "the equality implies that there are no carries", rather than to "the equality is false". ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2185771/19328 asks about counterexamples.

Answer (score 32):

Let's start with addition.  In a positional system like the one we ordinarily use, when we add two numbers, digits of different weights interact through carries.  If there are no carries out of any positions, the sum may be performed on each pair of digits independently and then the overall result assembled from those partial results by just arranging them in the right order.  For $0 \leq i < 5$, we have $2i < 10$; hence if all digits of a number are less than $5$ the addition trick will work.

The multiplication trick is similar.  For instance,
$$112 \cdot 112 = 11200 + 01120 + 00224 = 12544 \enspace,$$
while
$$211 \cdot 211 = 42200 + 02110 + 00211 = 44521 \enspace.$$
Note that there are no carries generated, either while computing the partial products or while computing the final sum.

While the condition $0 \leq i < 5$ works for any numbers of digits when computing $n+n$, the increase in the number of partial products means that the multiplication trick only works for relatively small numbers.  For instance,

$$ 11111112 \cdot 11111112 = 123456809876544 \enspace,$$

but

$$ 21111111 \cdot 21111111 = 445679007654321 \enspace. $$

The effect of the carries is initially visible in the middle digits, which depend on the most partial products.

Answer (score 12):

It is not merely a coincidence. Rather, it is a special case of the fact that *reversing* the coefficients of a polynomial is a *multiplicative* operation (curiously this is not  well known, cf. prior answers).

Let $\,f = \color{#c00}{a_n} x^n\, +\,\cdots\, +\,\color{#0af}{a_1} x\, +\, \color{#0a0}{a_0}\,$ be a polynomial in $x.\,$ Reversing its coefficients yields

$\quad\, \bar f = \color{#0a0}{a_0} x^n + \color{#0af}{a_1}x^{n-1} +\cdots + \color{#c00}{a_n} = x^n f(x^{-1}),\ $ the [reverse (or reciprocal)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_polynomial) of $\,f.$

It is [easy to show](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/640647/242) $\overline{fg}\, =\, \bar f\bar g,\,$ i.e. **polynomial reversal is multiplicative**. For example

$\qquad \begin{align} 
(1x+2)(1x+3)\, &= 1x^2+5x+6\, \overset{\large x\, =\, 10}\Longrightarrow\,  12\cdot 13\, =\, 156\\
\overset{\rm reverse}\Longrightarrow (2x+1)(3x+1)\, &= 6x^2+5x+1\ \ \Longrightarrow\,\ \ 21\cdot 31\, =\, 651
\end{align}$

Your examples are special cases when the product is a square (of linear polynomials). For the polynomials to yield *integer* reversals when evaluated at the radix $\,x=10\,$ it is necessary that all polynomials (including the product) have nonnegative coefficients less than the radix.

Answer (score 11):

I'll make it really simple - you could explain to your son the exact reason after reading the answer.

Let the 2-digit number in question be represented as: $10a+b$

Now, $$(10a+b)^2=100a^2+b^2+20ab$$
On reversing its digit, you get: $$(10b+a)^2=100b^2+a^2+20ba$$

Notice that, a 3 digit number can be represented as $100x+10y+z$, and that in the above case, IFF $$20ab<100;b^2<10;a^2<10$$are satisfied, **we can have numbers satisfying the property your son noticed. This is because, if any one of the 3 conditions above were not true, it would result in carried-over addition.** Eg: For 14, $4^2<10$ is clearly not true. It can be seen that: $$14*14=196=100*1^2+4^2+20*1*4$$
And that:
$$41*41=100*4^2+1^2+20*4*1\ne196$$
*So the only numbers satisfying it are:* $00,01,02,03,10,11,12,13,20,21,22,30,31$

---

For the second part of your question, it can be seen that:
$$(10a+b)+(10a+b)=2(10a+b)=20a+2b$$
And on reversing the digits,:
$$(10b+a)+(10b+a)=2(10b+a)=20b+2a$$
**Clearly, iff $20a,20b<100$ and $2a,2b<10$, i.e. $a,b<5$, the observation your son made holds.**

***So 14, unlike in the multiplication scenario, actually fulfills the above condition.*** (Hence $14+14=28$ & $41+41=82$)

*So the only numbers satisfying it are:* $00,01,02,03,04,10,11,12,13,14,20,21,22,30,31,33,40,41,44$

Comment: What about 44+44?

Comment: I checked and its 88

Comment: @Dror Have you considered publishing your finding? :-)

Comment: I wanted to write it in base 3 to fill the comment quota. I'll publish that I think :). I'm just kidding. Although I think you guys know too much to a point where you see meaning where there is mainly just utility.

Comment: @Dror Pretty sure I don't know too much.  I was only trying to politely point out that the lists of the only two-digit numbers whose digits are less than 5 is incomplete.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi I hope you recognize it begged my answer (Some would agree :)

Comment: @FabioSomenzi I do apologize.

Comment: @Dror No need to apologize.  It made me smile.  It is a good repartee.  Mine was also meant to be humorous.

Comment: Agreed. Will edit my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Motivated by the proofs above, I thought of the more general case:

Suppose that $a,b,c,d,x,y,z$ are integers such that $ 0 \le a,b,c,d,x,y,z < 10$. Furthermore, let $(10 a + b) \times (10c + d)= xyz$. Then, for what values of $a,b,c,d$ do we have $ (10b+a) \times (10d + c) = zyx$?

For example, $14 \times 12 = 168$ and $41 \times 21 = 861$. Extending the proofs provided by others in the above posts to the present case, we have
$$
 \left(10 a + b \right) \times \left( 10c + d\right) = 100 ac + 10(ad + bc) + bd.
$$

Similarly,
$$
 \left(10 b + a \right) \times \left( 10d + c\right) = 100 bd + 10(bc + ad) + ac.
$$

Suppose $0 \le ac,bd < 10$ and $ad+bc <10$. Then, there is no carry-over and we have that $ (10b+a) \times (10d + c) = zyx$.

This opens up a lot more possibilities. Fascinating stuff!