# Coefficients of some polynomials factorization

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, factoring

**EDITED**

---

If anyone is interested in this question,
now there are [OEIS draft](https://oeis.org/draft/A370747) and [repository](https://github.com/lesobrod/DigitsPolynomialFactorization) with detailed data.

---

Let $n,b\in\mathbb{N}$ and $P_{n_b}$ is polynomial whose coefficients *are digits* of $n$ in base $b$.
Let $Q_{1}(x) \cdot Q_{2}(x) \cdots Q_{m}(x)$ - polynomial factorization (over integers) of $P_{n_b}$.
I'm interested in *coefficients of such factorization*, especially *union of all factor's coefficients* $\mathcal{U}(n,b)$ of a given polynomial.

Let $n$ successively increase from $1$.
From the previous responses I learned that:

- $\mathcal{U}(n,b) \subseteq \{0, \dots, b-1\}$
  iff there are no carries when multiplying prime factors of $n$ (in base $b$)
- [Any  integer  sooner or later will appear](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/464410/coefficients-of-0-1-polynomials-factorization) in some $\mathcal{U}(n,b)$

I've found numerically that *there are certain patterns in the order

in which integer $z$ firstly appear* in  $\mathcal{U}(n,b)$
E.g. for $b=2$:
$1,0,-1,2,-2,3,-3,\{-4,4\},\{-5,5\},\{-6,6\},\{-7,7\},\{-8,8\},\dots$
(starting with $-4$ integers appear in pairs simultaneously)
Part of table for $b=10$:

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **z** | 1 | 2 | .. | 9 | 10 | -1 | -2 | .. | 10 | -9 |
| **n** | 1 | 2 | .. | 9 | 0 | 1001 | 1008 | .. | 28119 | 108009 |

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **z** | -10 | -11 | .. | 18 | -14 | .. |
| **n** | 621489 | 730158 | .. | 10809909 | 10951149 | .. |

*Are there any algebra or number theories laws behind these patterns, or it's just kind of misconception?*

Comment: I would encourage you to provide some explicit examples, in part because your writeup is too terse to express you ideas. Some issues i have are: 1/ You used \cdot in the polynomial factorization of $P_{n_b}$. So, are you referring to a specific polynomial factorization, which could be $ 1 \times P_{n_b}$,  the fully factorized form, or any possible factorization? 2/ Your post is for general $b$, but the link for "iff no carries" is only for $b = 2$. Did you verify the general $b$ case? 3/ Please clarify what you mean by $ -10 \leq b $. Are you using negative bases? (You might be) non-integer?

Comment: Related: [multiplicativity of reversing digits](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2182752/242) $\ \ $