# How to Prove Square Number?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-systems

Suppose that we have these numbers and their radix is $b$. How to prove that these numbers are square number?

1. $(12321)_b $for every $b > 3$
2. $(14641)_b$ for every $b > 6$
3. $(1234321)_b$ for every $b > 4$

Comment: I fixed your mathjax. Please see if your original meaning was retained.

Comment: Hint:  $x^4+2x^3+3x^2+2x+1=(x^2+x+1)^2$ and so on.

Comment: search 14641 on this site. Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1633311/prove-that-the-number-14641-is-the-fourth-power-of-an-integer-in-any-base-greate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray*}
[(111)_b]^2 =(12321)_b \\
[(11)_b]^4= (14641)_b \\
[(1111)_b]^2=(1234321)_b.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For example with part 1, $(12321)_b=b^4+2b^3+3b^2+2b+1$.  You could then try to find a polynomial (of degree $2$) that squares to this value.

Answer (score 0):

Just to help you started out with, here's how you prove 1.

$(12321)_b = b^4+2b^3+3b^2+2b+1 =(b^2+b+1)^2 $

And hence the given number in base $b \geq 4$ is a square.The rest are similar to the one I just did, you shouldn't have any problems.