# Invariance of number properties under different bases

Tags: number-theory, number-comparison

Are in number theory always numbers with basis 10 considered? I‘m asking which role the basis plays in number theoretic properties or notions like prime numbers for examples.

For example: the number 3 is a prime number.

When I take know the basis 3 to represent 3, then it is 10 what is not prime. However, 10 is still in $\mathbb Z$.

Knows somebody if bases play a role in theory of numbers? And if yes, are there invariant properties?

(Remark:
Basis 10: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, …

Basis  3 : 0, 1, 2, 10, 11, 12, 20, 21, 22, 100, …)

Comment: "10" is not prime in base 10, but is still prime in base 3.

Comment: @angryavian thats right, I had a big thinking error in assuming 10 in base 3 is not prime.

Comment: So this might sound like a dumb question, if a number is not what it's called (depending on it's base) then what is it, really? A cat is called a cat, nekko, chat, Katze, in various languages. The number 9 is: 1001(binary), 101(ternary), 21 (quaternary), 14 (quinary), 13 (senary), ... BUT WHAT IS IT REALLY? An object? The fact that it remains the same "thing" despite given different names makes it seem LESS abstract for some reason. Am I overthinking this? Please add some insights or point me in the right direction with some resources: What are these quanttative objects? Figments of out minds?

Comment: @mrwonderfulness You are asking a very interesting philosophical question. You have a choice - leave it unanswered and just work worry free with   numbers - or start down the rabbit hole. If you google _do numbers exist_ you will find lots of links to discussions and videos at various levels of philosophical and mathematical sophistication. There are also posts on the philososphy stackexchange - e.g. https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/451/do-numbers-exist-independently-from-observers

Comment: Ok, i see. It's one of "THOSE" questions :)
Thanks for the references!

Comment: I think what i find important as a starting point is if whatever numerical quality / property a number has, well...if those things that make it whatever the number "is" has no connection to the base it is written in. That fact that this is true, that it is somehow not connected to the decimal (or whatever) system...well, that really leads to the rabbit hole, doesn't it?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an interesting question, because it addresses the difference between what a number *is* and how we choose to name it or write it.

The properties of numbers that matter in mathematics (even? prime? square?) belong to the numbers themselves. They are the same whether you are speaking about them in English or in French, whether you write them in base 10 or base 2 or using Roman numerals.

There are some properties that do depend on the representations in particular bases. These are often part of "recreational mathematics" - puzzles or observations that are fun to think about but don't often make their way into "serious" mathematics.  For example, $14641$ is the fourth power of some number. Find it. Then figure out when the number with those digits thought of as in some other base $b$ is also a fourth power, and why.

> [Prove that the number 14641 is the fourth power of an integer in any base greater than 6?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1633311/prove-that-the-number-14641-is-the-fourth-power-of-an-integer-in-any-base-greate)

Comment: That is really interesting, I‘m astonished.

Comment: Can you please check my comment above and if possible provide some sources for your information? I'd like to learn more about this! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Most properties such as being prime or being a perfect square stay invariant in any base. If $n$ divides $m$ in one base, it will divide $m$  in any other base as well.
The number of digits and the digits which are allowed depends on the base.
Numbers are the same, using different bases changes the way we express that number.

Comment: That is great, thank you

Comment: This makes sense, but begs the question: THEN WHAT IS A NUMBER?